# Finding out when someone purchased your app

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, app-store

Does anyone know how I can find out the date when someone purchased my app using MonoTouch in the app?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I do not think you can get the information for the application itself - only for in-app purchases (where you get a [receipt](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StoreKitGuide/VerifyingStoreReceipts/VerifyingStoreReceipts.html)).

You can probably get a *guesstimate* of the date based on the installation date (e.g. file timestamps) but that won't cover re-installing the application (same device), installing the application on another device...

Another way it to communicate with a server application that will register the "first use" date (again the issue of re-installing and multiple devices must be considered).

Depending on **why** you need this information the above might be useful or only part of a more complex solution...

Comment: Thanks you have confirmed what I already believed to be the case. Good stuff